# Open fragment from adapter RecyclerView

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, fragment

i have some troubles with my app. I have recyclerView with CardView. And i want to open new fragment with description of info... But it doesn't matter.

This is my adapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.DataViewHolder>{

//here
private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener mClickListener;

public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cardView;
    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewRegion;

    public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewRegion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRegion);
    }
}

private List<DataJSON> dataList;

RVAdapter(List<DataJSON> dataList){
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    DataViewHolder dvh = new DataViewHolder(v);
    return dvh;
}

private DataJSON getItem(int position){
    return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(dataList.get(position).getPierName());
    holder.textViewRegion.setText(dataList.get(position).getRegion());

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("myLog", "Click-clack position " + position);
            if (mClickListener != null){
                Log.d("myLog", "mClickListener != null");
                mClickListener.onClick(position);
            } else {Log.d("myLog", "mClickListener = null");}
        }
    });
}

//here
public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    void onClick(int parameter);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
```

}

In onBindViewHolder i have onClick where i call OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onClick in MainActivity.

This is MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RVAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener{
private CardViewFragment cardViewFragment;
private DetailFragment detailFragment;

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("MyTag", "onCreate");

    //Create FragmentManager
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Initialization fragments
    cardViewFragment = new CardViewFragment();
    detailFragment = new DetailFragment();


    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, cardViewFragment, CardViewFragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(int parameter) {
    Log.d("myLog", "Hi, from MainActivity");
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, detailFragment, DetailFragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

I have an error, that mClickListener is null object, and understand it,
but i really don't know, how to fix it.

This is CardViewFragment

```
public class CardViewFragment extends Fragment implements RVAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

public static final String TAG = "CardViewFragment";

private List<DataJSON> dataJSONList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
RVAdapter rvAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_view_fragment, container, false);

    dataJSONList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    loadDataFromServer();
    //testData();

    rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(this, dataJSONList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

    getActivity();
    return rootView;
}

private void testData(){
    //dataJSONList.add(new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia"));
    //dataJSONList.add(new DataJSON(1, "kek", "Lol", "Scream"));
    DataJSON data2 = new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia");
    dataJSONList.add(data2);
}

String strJson;
private void loadDataFromServer()  {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://gesmetrics.ru/testpiers.php").build();
            Response response;

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                strJson = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return strJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            Log.d("myLog", strJson);

            //DataJSON data2 = new DataJSON(0, "RiverIsland", "Moscow", "Moscow is the capital of Russia");
            //dataJSONList.add(data2);

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strJson);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = object.getInt("pierId");
                    String name = object.getString("pierName");
                    String region = object.getString("region");
                    String description = object.getString("description");
                    DataJSON data = new DataJSON(i, name, region, description);
                    //nothing happens here
                    dataJSONList.add(data);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Issue");
            }
            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    };
    task.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(int parameter) {

}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RVAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener{
private CardViewFragment cardViewFragment;
private DetailFragment detailFragment;

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("MyTag", "onCreate");

    //Create FragmentManager
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Initialization fragments
    cardViewFragment = new CardViewFragment();
    detailFragment = new DetailFragment();


    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, cardViewFragment, CardViewFragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(int parameter) {
    Log.d("myLog", "Hi, from MainActivity");
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, detailFragment, DetailFragment.TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `mClickListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pass the click listener via your adapter's constructor.

   ```
   RVAdapter(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener,List<DataJSON> dataList){
       mClickListener = listener;
       this.dataList = dataList;
   }
   ```
2. Do the fragment transaction inside your **CardViewFragment** class

   ```
   public class CardViewFragment extends Fragment implements RVAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

   @Override
   public void onClick(int parameter) {
       //either add fragment
       //getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       //        .add(new DetailFragment(), null)
       //        .commit();
       //or if you defined any container for DetailFragment(like frame layout) in your fragment layout file which is activity_card_view_fragment.xml just use replace
       getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
               .commit();

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: But, what i must add in (rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(dataJSONList);) in my first fragment with RecyclerView?

Comment: No, you need to implement `OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener` on your fragment or wherever you set your adapter and pass it on adapter creation. Try this `new RvAdapter(this, dataJSONList);`

Comment: `new RvAdapter(this, dataJSONList);` in my First Fragment with recyclerView doesn't work
"Error:(43, 26) error: incompatible types: CardViewFragment cannot be converted to OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener"

Comment: implement the listener interface first. Change your fragment like this `CardViewFragment implements OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener`

Comment: Please, look up on my question, i have added my CardViewFragment.
Maybe some problems in empty OnClick?
Because it still doesn't work
Sorry for me

Comment: yes, sure!
Thank you a lot!
I have no errors, but it still doesn't work)

Comment: I want to help you. Can you please tell me what's not working right now?

Comment: I need to open my new fragment from CardView with position.
In my MainActivity, i implements RVAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener, and have onClick, but it doesn't call new fragment. MainActivity will be up, in my question, I would be very grateful if you can help me with this.

Comment: 1. You don't need to implement `OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener` on your `MainActivity.` Because it has no use right now. 2. Do your fragment transaction inside your `CardViewFragment` class's `onClick` method

Comment: Glad to help you